# How can i add my copyright in the footer?

Tags: magento2.3, footer, copyright

The copyright is removed in the footer. In which file can i recover it and which text to add?
So now there is not copyright rule displayed at all. Maybe this file something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I update my answer, where I added where is the template file path, please check that one.

Comment: I updated a printscreen..

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **Content -> Design -> Configurations**
2. Edit last configuration
3. In footer tab you will find **copyright** section
4. Update desired copyright text here

Comment: I think the original footer file is changed.... so this not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this steps :

1. Open Magento Admin
2. Go To Content -> Design -> Configurations
3. There are different theme options at different level like website/Store. See this : https://prnt.sc/uwja4x
4. Select from which level you want to change it and click on respective "Edit" Options.
5. Now reach to the "Footer" section where you will find the options like this : "Copyright" see this one : https://prnt.sc/uwjaqf
6. You can make the changes and save it. Do the caching and then check it on frontend.

**Default Magneto Footer Phtml Path** :

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml

**Custom Theme Footer File Path** :

> app/code/Vendor/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml

Comment: I think the original footer file is changed.... so this not solved the problem.

Comment: @Parts Currently anythnig show in that copyright or not?

Comment: No nothing there

Comment: So first you need to check does the disable from xml or what?

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand where to check?

Comment: I update my answer, with the phtml file path where it is.

Comment: I add a printscreen with the file. Can you check?

Comment: Confirm that file call on frontend or not? By template path hints.

Comment: Sorry Dhiren. How and where can i check this?

Comment: Hi Dhiren, did you read my response?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Content >> Configuration.
2. Edit the active theme
3. Click on Footer tab
4. Edit the copyright Text

[image]

After changes Run Below command :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

[image]

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I think the original footer file is changed.... so this not solved the problem.

Comment: you want to show copyright using phtml file ?

Comment: Where is this file located?

Comment: Hello, can you answer this?